# Analysing dates using 20 day fixed windows in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I currently have some data that contains categories and datestamps, example below:

| date | cat |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A |
| 2021-01-03 | B |
| 2021-01-06 | B |
| 2021-01-08 | A |
| 2021-02-05 | A |
| 2021-02-15 | B |
| 2021-06-30 | A |
| 2021-07-18 | A |
| 2021-07-30 | A |

I'm trying to figure out how to code the following question:

- Which events with category A have occurred more than 20 days from the next eligible A date?

So, if I was looking at the above dataframe and using a fixed 20 day window, I would have the following dataframe as the result:

| date | cat |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A |
| 2021-02-05 | A |
| 2021-06-30 | A |
| 2021-07-30 | A |

I'm comfortable with filtering for the categories, and I know how to do a rolling 20 day window. I'm unsure how to do a window in this way though, with it "reseting" once it has reached 20 days from the eligible event.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean previous event? If not please explain how 2021-01-01 is in the output if the next event 2021-01-08 is within 20 days.

Comment: @ScootCork sure, sorry it wasn't clear.
So I want to look at the first event date per category, so in this case, the first date for category A being 2021-01-01. 
I then want to look at the next first date that is more than 20 days away from this. So in this case, 2021-02-05. Then I want to look at the next earliest date that is at least 20 days away (2021-06-30) etc.

Kind of like a 20-day rolling window, but it's more 'fixed' in a sense. Hopefully that makes sense.